# Need assistance with my Code for Length with Trim in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have my primary key in column F - 4 length char
I have entity name in column X - 1 to 40 length characters

I need to concatenate both columns and produce result in column CD.

But the length of the column CD should be less than 20 characters.
My below code works fine when total characters are more than 20, but it throws error when the concatenation is less then 20.

Can someone suggest where I am going wrong ?

```
Range("CD1") = "Standard_Beneficiary"
For a = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(a, "CD").Value = Cells(a, "F").Value & "_" & Left(Cells(a, "X"), Len(Cells(a, "X").Value) - 10)
 Next a
```

Comment: `Cells(a, "CD").Value = Left(Cells(a, "F").Value & "_" & Cells(a, "X").Value, 20)`

Comment: Excellent Time. This code worked. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Left(Cells(a, "X"),Len(Cells(a, "X").Value) - 10)` Only works when the length of `Cells(a,"X").Value` is larger than 10 characters, otherwise the number of characters you want from the left side is negative, which is impossible of course.

You can either use an if-statement, or use something like

`application.worksheetfunction.max(1,Len(Cells(a, "X").Value) - 10)`

instead of `Len(Cells(a, "X").Value) - 10`, to make sure it's always a positive number.